# Exclude certain directories in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been porting (very simply) a Python script from Windows to Linux (directory changes mostly), and I want to add a few new features to it.
The script is used to update mods on a game server. All mods are located in ShooterGame/Content/Mods/. Some mods are included by default (TheCenter and 11111111) - every other mod is located in the same folder as the default ones, but the names consist of random numbers.

I've been trying to exclude the 2 default directories and then build a list of contents of the ShooterGame/Content/Mods/ folder, but I've failed to do so. 
This is the code that I've tried to use to exclude just the TheCenter folder:

```
def build_list_of_mods(self):
    """
    Build a list of all installed mods by grabbing all directory names from the mod folder
    :return:
    """
    exclude = ["TheCenter"]
    if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(self.working_dir, "ShooterGame/Content/Mods/")):
        return
    for curdir, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(self.working_dir, "ShooterGame/Content/Mods/")):
        for d in dirs:
            dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude]
            self.installed_mods.append(d)
        break
```

It doesn't work, sadly. Have I missed something or just done everything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `topdown=True` to the `os.walk()` function like this:

```
for curdir, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(self.working_dir, "ShooterGame/Content/Mods/"), topdown=True):
```

Plus I cannot try it but maybe `dirs[:]` should be outside of the *for-loop*, as the documentation says:

> When topdown is true, the caller can modify the dirnames list in-place (e.g., via del or slice assignment), and walk will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in dirnames;

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want `self.installed_mods` to contain the values of `dirs` without the values of `exclude`.
You could simply call `dirs.remove()` with the values of `exclude` and then append the content of `dirs` to `self.installed_mods`.
Or in a shorter way: `self.installed_mods.extend([dir for dir in dirs if dir not in exclude])`.

Comment: Thanks. I think that did the job. End result was this: for curdir, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(self.working_dir, "ShooterGame/Content/Mods/")):
            for d in dirs:
                self.installed_mods.extend([dir for dir in dirs if dir not in exclude])
            break

Comment: Oh, it wasn't really the case after all. http://pastebin.com/Y5X7ny97 just keeps updating in a loop - but it excludes the correct folders. The loop is a problem, though.

Comment: The `for d in dirs:` part needs to be removed

Comment: Then i just get `NameError: name 'd' is not defined`

Comment: And removing (d) from the append, seems to make it look outside the mods folder.

Comment: Nevermind, seems to be fixed now. The `break` wasn't positioned correctly.